# In Cypress.io how do I tick an item in a span that contains an element with the same name but I only want to tick one of the items

Tags: javascript, css, automation, cypress

When using cypress how do I tick one of the items when they are in a table and then a span.

```html
<table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-cy="todoItem">
      <td class="undone">
        <span data-cy="markAsCompleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        Buy Milk
        <span data-cy="markAsDeleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign close" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cy="todoItem">
      <td class="undone">
        <span data-cy="markAsCompleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        Call Dad
        <span data-cy="markAsDeleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign close" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-cy="todoItem">
      <td class="undone">
        <span data-cy="markAsCompleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
        Fill Gas
        <span data-cy="markAsDeleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign close" aria-hidden="true">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to click this part of the HTML as it is a tick to cross out "Fill Gas".

```
<span data-cy="markAsCompleted" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

This what I tried

```
cy.get('[data-cy=markAsCompleted]').contains('Fill Gas').click()
```

the error I got was that there are 3 more elements with cy=markAsCompleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you want is contained in the cell (`<td>`), so find that first, then within it the span that requires the click (presume it has the event handler)

```
cy.contains('td', 'Fill Gas')           // target the cell
  .find('[data-cy=markAsCompleted]')    // move to span
  .click()
  .parent()                             // back to the cell
  .should('have.class', 'done')         // check the click results
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Now how do I assert that the td has a class of "done"?

Comment: The steps I added to the command chain should check the done class.